# RxJava: Combine hot and cold observable

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have two Observables. They are both of type `Observable<T>`.

One is a cold one called `initialValueObservable` which simply emits from a list of items by a `Observable.from()`.

The other one is a hot one called `valueUpdateObservable` which is a `PublishSubject` that notifies the subscriber when there is a new item.

In the client I want to subscribe to both so I get the initial value from the `initialValueObservable` and the updates published by `valueUpdateObservable`.
My initial approach was to merge them but I think that won't work as the `initialValueObservable` will send `onComplete` at which point the new items emit by the `valueUpdateObservable` won't arrive.

Comment: When you do a merge the `onComplete` is only sent when all of the source observables, in this case both, complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a merge the `onComplete` is only sent when all of the source observables, in this case both, complete.

Take this (c# Rx.NET) code as an example:

```
Observable
    .Return(42L)
    .Merge(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Take(3))
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

It produces:

```
42
0
1
2
```

I'd be astounded if RxJava did anything different.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes looking for this, here is an example

```
Observable.concat(
    coldObservable.doOnComplete{ () -> Log.d(TAG, "cold observable completed"); },
    hotObservable.doOnComplete{ () -> Log.d(TAG, "hot observable completed") }
.subscribe()
```

Will Log all of the coldObservable's value followed by "cold observable completed" and then all of the hotObvservable's values.  "hot observable completed" will not be Logged assuming it's something like a click listener that doesn't have a completed state